# Why is the alert displayed two times on button click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, require

Could you please tell me why alerts display two times on button click?

here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/vtmYAG2d1gmnPjnxovJw?p=preview

```
/*global define, console */

define(['app'], function(app){
   'use strict';

    app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.login = function () {
          alert("Login is clicked")
        };

    }]);

});
```

Comment: That's weird. It seems to launch the ng-click both on mousedown and mouseup - if you click the button holding mouse down, move the mouse away from the button and then release the click, it only fires one ng-click.

Comment: so what is work around ..is there any possiblity that I am using Ionic with require js may be that why it work like that

Comment: can we use requirejs with ionic framework

Comment: I used ng-mousedown instead of ng-click and it fires once. I think it might be Ionic related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a newer version of Ionic it works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/K2BLrUyOEeoDxHc9LyTl?p=preview

I used http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js

your example uses 
http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    ionic:'http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min',
},
shim: {
    ionic : {exports : 'ionic'}
}, priority: [
    'ionic'
],

deps: [
    'bootstrap'
]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed you have used obsolete minified version of ionic and requirejs non-minified.

Just change your ionic version to --
http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js

and requireJs to 
RequireJS 2.1.17

it's working fine ...change version in your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The digest cycle runs at least two times by angularjs. So, probably the reason for the alert is appearing two times is digest cycle.

But others said to change version and you would get alert calling only once. But if you don't want to change the version, there's a workaround to this:

```
$scope.login = function () {
   alert("Login is clicked");
   $scope.login = function(){
     return false;
   }
 };
```

[working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9z4MJLain1E3QndML3k?p=preview)

This method allows you to call function only once. It might be helpful for others who want to stop digest cycle.